# Setting advanced recurring payment in paypal

Tags: html, api, paypal

I need to create a Paypal subscription with this configuration: 39.95€ for the first 12 months (39.95€ every month), then 79.9€ every month.
I wrote this code

```html
<form name="checkout_confirmation" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="79.9" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="39.95" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="12" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M" />
</form>
```

but I think that this will create a subscription with a trial period of 12 months paid 39.95€ (and not 39.95 each month)... am I right? 
How can I create a trial period of 12 months paid 39.95 each month?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially PayPal Payments Standard subscriptions (which is what you're using here) doesn't support more than one billing cycle for the trial period — so you would have to bill the entire 12 months all at once, and then start billing 79.90€ every month after that.

Alternatively, you might want to look at [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec-integration/#), specifically [Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht-ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/) — which does support the ability to have trial periods that bill more than once.